# Need help regarding JPA entity mapping

Tags: spring, jpa, orm, mapping, entity

I'm fairly new to ORM. I'm having trouble deciding how exactly I should map the following entities.

1. DiscussionThread
2. Post
3. User
4. AnonymousUser

**DiscussionThread** would be something similar to the ones we see in bulletin boards online. It would contain a list of **Post** which would be posted by **User**. However, I do not want the **User** to reveal his/her identity while posting in the **DiscussionThread**.
In order to achieve that I created a list of proxy usernames denoted by the entity **AnonymousUser**. Thus, whenever a **User** decides to make a **Post** in a **DiscussionThread**, he would be posting as an **AnonymousUser**. Any further **Post** made by the same **User** in that **DiscussionThread** would be linked to the same **AnonymousUser**.The **User** will have different **AnonymousUser** names in different **DiscussionThreads**. An instance of **AnonymousUser** may be used by two different users on two different threads.

In simpler words, there will be one **AnonymousUser** for one **User** in each **DiscussionThread**.

I have created the following POJO entities, but I'm stuck in how I should map them to each other.

```
public class AnonymousUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String displayPicture;

    //Not sure how to make relationships here
    private Set<DiscussionThread> discussionThreads;

    private Set<User> users;
}

public class DiscussionThread {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String description;
}

public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    private String username;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you basically described:

[image]

Don't know if it's right or not but this is one way you could diagram and think about such problems. This is Chen's database notation in Visio.